# 'function' object has no attribute 'get' in django

Tags: python, django, forms, decorator

I am trying to make a user not able to ask a Question only when he is logged in.

This is the error I'm getting in my terminal window:

```
    Internal Server Error: /ask_question/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/rayan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
    File "/home/rayan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
    File "/home/rayan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py",  line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
    [23/Jul/2020 17:19:16] "GET /ask_question/ HTTP/1.1" 500 62327
```

I am using a decorator, this is the code in my decorators.py:

```
def usersOnly(view_func):
    def func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return view_func
        else:
            return redirect('login')
    return func
```

And this is the code in my views.py:

```
@usersOnly
def ask_question(request):
    form = AskQuestion()
    if request.method == "POST":
        asker = request.user
        form = AskQuestion(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            id = form.cleaned_data.get('id')
            return redirect(f'/question/{id}/')
dic = {
    "form":form,
}
return render(request, 'blogs/ask_question.html', dic)
```

And this is the code from my models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    asker = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am trying to allow only the logged in users to ask a question, if the user isn't logged in, he will be redirected to the login page. But it is giving me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *call* the function in the decorator, and return the *result* of the function, not the function itself:

```
def usersOnly(view_func):
    def func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect('login')
    return func
```

But what you here aim to do, already exists. You can make use of the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('login'))
def ask_question(request):
    # …
```